# Is this a viable legitimate way to circumvent NSA spying on me?

Tags: security

If I set up my own email server in my basement using Ubuntu along with my own domain, own SMTP server, hosted the emails in my machine, ran a pretty wicked good firewall, would that circumvent spying on my email?

More info:
1 I realize once the email gets replied to outside of my environment that it loses any safeguards I could set up. I'm not concerned about this. I'm more trying to find out if in theory this is possible.

1. For the sake of argument, if it is doable with relative ease, assume I would/will encrypt any protocols if they aren't traditionally encrypted.   This includes DNS too.
2. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the spying on Americans (and the world) seems to be targeted at all the big players we all fall back on use for all our basic communication needs (Apple, Google, Microsoft, AT&T, Sprint, etc).  Lets assume this "prism" program has taken the entire infrastructure of America's fiber optics and has large portions of it (most of which run near the HQ of those formally mentioned companies).  So if I stop using those companies and just run my own email server, is there still a legitimate threat that they could usurp all communication on everyone?  What about the ISPs? And does the data being encrypted matter or do they have a way of cracking that too?

No smart remarks. I'm just trying to figure out how the specific of this works.  Since 95% of us use Google, Apple, Microsoft, AT&T in one way or another, naturally setting up your own infrastructure would defeat that, right?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I would be using Ubuntu to run an email server instead of relying on yahoo, google, etc

Comment: All other questions on NSA have been closed on this site....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Ubuntu but the extent to which various governments particularly but not exclusively US and UK are spying on us. The same arguments could be made about any device connected to the internet regardless of which OS is used

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as you don't use the Internet for it at all.

Once you start relaying packets to a third party, all bets are off. SMTP has no end-to-end security. Say you use HTTPS to craft a message on your own mail server, and your mail server uses SSL/TLS encryption to talk to an SMTP server. You have no control of who is intercepting at that server. You have no influence over whether that server uses encryption to talk to the next server on the way to the recipient. You encrypt only your communication with one endpoint in a long chain, and hope for the best with the rest.

Running your own mail server in your basement adds as much security as hand-writing the message by candlelight in a closet before typing it in. It's still going out to the Internet where you have no influence over who encrypts, inspects or stores it. Adding your own e-mail server as one extra link in long untrusted chain does not help at all.

> So why then (if you have been following) do the ISPs seem to not be targeted or even mentioned at all?

Because you haven't been paying attention.

[Communications Assistance for Law Enforcement Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_Assistance_for_Law_Enforcement_Act)
[Lawful interception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection#Lawful_interception)
[FCC: Communications Assistance for Law Enforcement Act and Broadband Access and Services](http://hraunfoss.fcc.gov/edocs_public/attachmatch/FCC-06-56A1.pdf)

The only way to make it difficult for your e-mail to be intercepted is to [encrypt it before it leaves your computer](http://lifehacker.com/180878/how-to-encrypt-your-email) so that it can only be decrypted by the recipient.

Comment: Okay let's forget the idea of the mail server and look at something you can run directly on ubuntu: owncloud.  You've heard of this program no doubt? It could be any private based cloud app.  Dropbox is seamless, it runs better than any cloud based file sharing service hands down. 

Let's say this "owncloud" was similar to dropbox, except you used your own computer as the server.  Data is going from one computer to another using the wires and infrastructure of your ISP and whoever else owns those fiber optic wires.  Is that info safe?

Comment: Another service with promise (which I'm actually testing right this moment) is called BT Sync, torrent technology without the torrent client, just private file sharing in folders with whoever has your "seceret" key.  Could this be viewed as info that isn't "spy material"? It is encrpted with a 256bit encryption.

Comment: I'd think you just have to encrypt anything to really prevent stuff. And then also somehow prevent the use of NSA-approved algorithms, because it is not entirely unfeasible the NSA has cryptanalysis tools against its own algorithms the world doesn't know about. So no SHA-2.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your ISP will be connected back to them in some way, I mean think about it, it's the largest tactical step in obtaining data from users; go directly to their source. Though I would say that if you are indeed using this private mail service you've set up, it could still be tapped from the cables, the ISP or even the backbones which support the ISP's in the first place so it's not going to be as secure as you'd like it to be.

SSL methods are indeed quite secure as in an SSL transfer the data is encrypted on the client or server with a key that only the client or server can access. Therefore you could use SSL to communicate with other servers in a safe manner on the web.

Does this answer your question at all?

Comment: I agree with you and thought the same thing. So why then (if you have been following) do the ISPs seem to not be targeted or even mentioned at all?  The targets are the Internet media giants along with the telecom companies.  Why gather googles info when you can gather comcasts?

Comment: Google has a more public front than ISP's tend to, people will respond in a more abrupt manner if they realise it's the services they use every day that they afraid of but they may forget to realise that they could be targeted by the very thing allowing them to access such services as broadband is so natural to humans now. ISP's though, do not seem to have what things like Google have; blogs, groups, social websites etc.. There's not much room to get the word out there and answer people's questions so it's less public.

Comment: so as this blatently is against the very foundation of what this country was founded on in the first place, can we safely say this is offically yhe end of the republic?  Nevermind that's nothing to do with an email server.

Comment: As much as this is an Ubuntu ask community and I'm obliged to say that we should no longer continue this; I'll leave this thread with this: I'm British and it's come to recent news that for months now our intelligence agency here has been feeding the NSA and itself with petaflops of information that is MORE than just metadata. It's sickening to feel this invaded but we will find ways around it. Hope I helped, the question above seems more in-depth..

Comment: We always got John Conner.

Answer (score 0):

If data flows through it, your government knows about it.

The more you try to hide, the more you stand out as someone with something to hide, which invites more scrutiny.

The only real solution is to unplug, completely and hide in a deep cave in the ground that no one knows about except you. Although I'm sure the powers to be are outfitting insects with surveillance devices to get into every nook and crannies on the planet to find out what or who is there.